# How can I extract the array indices from a xarray.rio.clip operation?

Tags: python, netcdf, rioxarray, xarray

I have a line of code that clips a Dataset from a larger `xarray.core.dataset.Dataset`.

```
clipped = ds.rio.clip([user_polygon], crs=4326, all_touched=True)
```

I need to process many of these large datasets (NetCDF files) and this clip operation is time consuming. Is there a way to get the array indices so that I can access the data directly in subsequent extractions? Something like

```
coords = [(53, 1002), (53, 1003), (54, 1002), (54, 1003)]
clipped = ds[coords]
```

Comment: If anyone else has this problem, try timing your code. `.clip` may not be the problem.